# Preview with editing before printing

Tags: java, c++, printing

How to organize a preview before printing, so that the document in the preview can be edited?

For example, the print shows a table of three columns in the preview want to change something in one (not all three, but only at first) column, clicked the mouse in the right place, change the text, press Enter, the modified text should be preserved and print, as well as continue to the next time the print was a plaque with the earlier changes.

What libraries are better suited for this task, where there may be similar examples or tutorials

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Take a look into JTable